# Static Util methods vs Instance Util methods - Which one is good?

Tags: java, methods, static

Keeping Util class methods static is a good practice or instance methods are good?

Comment: Why on earth would they be instance methods?

Comment: Why do I get down votes for this question? Please somebody explain. when I get some queries I ask, is it really wrong?

Comment: I consider this a valid question. 1. If you want to use your Util class in EL (i.e. in JSF templates), then you'll need instance methods and an outjected Util bean instance, since EL doesn't support accessing static variables/methods. 2. Using a static instance of Util class allows to easily swap it in testing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a method is an utility method then it has no meaning in being associated to an instance of an object so there is no reason to make it an instance method.

An instance method should be something that is meaningful to a specific instance of a specific class.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you have an Util class with static methods so that you don't need to create an instance of your Util class.

I don't see the point in having an instance of an Util class, so I'd say keep the methods static.

Answer (score 1):

if your method  is not depend on other non static member. your method should be static.
i think here you are making utility pack so. method should static if it is not depend on non static member :)

generally util has no instance of util class

Comment: Thanks for the details, here I try utility class